# C# Called method is ignored with no error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a C# Windows Form program in which there are a number of called Methods (what in VB I called Subs). Excuse me if I'm using the wrong terms, new to C#. One of these methods is being ignored, CreateFolder().  When I set break points to debug and step through, the program gets to the called method and goes right through it like it like it was a blank line, no errors warning just goes through.  The program is a bit large so I'm including what I hope is helpful.  Sorry if too much. The method (sub) not being executed is CreateFolder(). Again, the debugger will stop on this line[CreateFolder()] in the ProcessEmail() routine but just goes on without going to the called code.  Thoughts?

```
public partial class FrmProcessNew : Form
    {
       ...bunch of global vaiables

        private void FrmProcessNew_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chkBoxTesting.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testing"]); //check if test to ignore bad credit cards
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessEmail();  //check for, process and then move new Outlook emails
        }
        public void ScrollBox(string box)   //try to get scroll box right
        {
            if (box == "Text")
            {
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        if (box == "List")
            { listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; }
        }
        public static int GetLineNumber(COMException ex)  //Get the line number if an error occurs - from stack overflow
        {
            var lineNumber = 0;
            const string lineSearch = ":line ";
            var index = ex.StackTrace.LastIndexOf(lineSearch);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                var lineNumberText = ex.StackTrace.Substring(index + lineSearch.Length);
                if (int.TryParse(lineNumberText, out lineNumber))
                {
                }
            }
            return lineNumber;
        }

        private void ProcessEmail() // Process the  new email
        {
            while (inboxFolder.Items.Count == 0) //check for any email in Inbox
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Inbox is empty - Listening for New emails!\r\n");
                ScrollBox("Text");
                textBox1.Update();
                Delay();  //wait 5 seconds
            }
            CreateFolder(); //Create new destination folder to move processed emails to - NOT FORWARDING TO THIS SUB!!

            try
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem in inboxFolder.Items)
                {
                  ....processing stuff
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
            {
                ....capture error
            }
            finally
            {
                ....reset  stuff
            }
         }

       public void CreateFolder()  //Create Outlook Folders to store processed emails = NEVER GETS TO THIS CODE!!!
       {
            DateTime fldDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (fldDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)  //must process with a Friday date, set date to next Friday
            { 
               fldDate = NextFriday(fldDate); 
            }
            String myYear = fldDate.ToString("yyyy");
            string myMonth = fldDate.ToString("MM");
            string myDay = fldDate.ToString("dd");  //day of the month
            string fileDate = (myYear.ToString()) + "-" + (myMonth.ToString()) + "-" + myDay; // build the Date for Destination "file";
            try
            {olDestinationFolder = ns.Folders[mailBoxName].Folders[("done")].Folders[(fileDate)]; }
            catch
            { olDestinationFolder = ns.Folders[mailBoxName].Folders[("done")].Folders.Add(fileDate); }
            try
            { olBadCreditFolder = ns.Folders[mailBoxName].Folders[("done")].Folders[(fileDate)].Folders[("BadCredit")]; }
            catch
            { olBadCreditFolder = ns.Folders[mailBoxName].Folders[("done")].Folders[(fileDate)].Folders.Add("BadCredit"); }
            try
            { olNonOrderEmails = ns.Folders[mailBoxName].Folders[("done")].Folders[(fileDate)].Folders[("Non-OrderEmails")]; }
            catch
            { olNonOrderEmails = ns.Folders[mailBoxName].Folders[("done")].Folders[(fileDate)].Folders.Add("Non-OrderEmails"); }

        }
        private void Delay()  //If no emails then want 5 seconds and try again
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("Inbox is empty - Listening for New emails!\r\n");
            ScrollBox("Text");
            textBox1.Update();
            // await Task.Delay(5000);  //Wait 5 seconds for new email
            var t = Task.Run(async delegate
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5));
                ScrollBox("Text");
                return 42;
            });
        }
       static DateTime NextFriday(DateTime fldDate)  //Find the next FRIDAY date.
        {
            do
            {
                fldDate = fldDate.AddDays(1);
            }
            while (fldDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday);   
            return fldDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To start with - remove all of the `try`/`catch` blocks. You should learn to code without using them unless you know that you have an unavoidable and specific exception that you can meaningfully handle - that means very few occasions that you'll actually use error handling. Learning to code without them means that you'll learn how to write safe code in the first place and errors won't so easily be "ignored". Please try your code without the exception handling and let us know if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Also, don't use the whacky `while (inboxFolder.Items.Count == 0) { Delay(); }` loop to check for email - it'll freeze your UI. Use a Windows Forms Timer to check every 5 seconds.